# Creating an instance of a class that implements an interface based on the class name?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, reflection, interface

Is there a way to generate an instance of a class that implements an interface based on the *name* of the class?

I am trying:

```
var ClassReference:Object = getDefinitionByName("movement.OuterSpaceMovement") as IMovement;
var m:IMovement = new ClassReference as IMovement;
trace("startup..." + m);
```

-But I am getting an error message ReferenceError: Error #1065 (OuterSpaceMovement) not defined.

I have several classes that implement the same interface (IMovement) but I need to be able to generate new instances of these classes and then pass these instances as a datatype (IMovement datatype) to other classes...

So then I tried:

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("OuterSpaceMovement") as Class;
var m:IMovement = new ClassReference() as IMovement;
```

and this doesn't seem to work...but the following

```
var m:IMovement = new OuterSpaceMovement();
```

does??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ClassReference should be of type Class, so:

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("movement.OuterSpaceMovement") as Class;
var m:IMovement = new ClassReference() as IMovement;
```

This should work, unless there is a problem with the class definition (it must be included in the build, so you have to import OuterSpaceMovement at least once somewhere in your program, or include it explicitly in your build settings or compiler options).

And, of course, OuterSpaceMovement must implement IMovement. ;)

Comment: Thanks, this does help, but I am still getting an "undefined" error message...added some detail above. Can anyone explain what the difference is??

Comment: Like I said: You must include the class at some point, in order for getDefinitionByName() to find it.  `new OuterSpaceMovement();` is explicit: The compiler imports the class file, because it "knows" the class is needed.  When you call the class by name, there is no explicit reference, and you have to manually make sure the compiler includes the class definition - it can't be found at runtime, if it isn't there!  That `new OuterSpaceMovement()` could actually be anywhere in your program - then the getDefinitionByName() call would work, as well.